# Is there a way to create superuser for Django apps on Heroku without using the CLI?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, git, heroku

I changed my app to use PostgreSQL on Heroku instead of the SQLite database that I have been using in development. Now I want to log into my admin portal on my hosted app, but I am not sure how to create a superuser.

Is there a way to push my local database to my Heroku database? I have been deploying through GitHub (not using the Heroku CLI) so I was wondering if there was a way without using the CLI.

If there isn't a way without using the Heroku CLI, could someone tell me how I would init the Heroku git repository, considering the fact that I already have a GitHub repository that I have been using?

This is my `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
import dj_database_url

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple ways you can do this:

1. Include a [DataMigration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) in the migrations file, this can be done with `./manage.py makemigrations <app_name> --empty`. In that file you can write a datamigration that adds a superuser.
2. You can create a custom start script for the app, in that script, invoke a [ManagementCommand](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) that ensures a superuser is always there.

Comment: if i have an existing git repo, do you know how I could also use the heroku cli within the same project folder?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to push my local database to my Heroku database?

Yes, if you are using the same database software locally are you are on Heroku. For example you can [push a database into Heroku Postgres using the Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-pg-push-source-target). But if you are still developing with SQLite (which is not recommended as these products aren't drop-in replacements for each other) there is no simple way to push your database.

I know you are asking for a solution without using the Heroku CLI, but I'm still going to recommend using it.

Use of the Heroku CLI and your deployment method are unrelated. In fact, command-line deployment doesn't even use the CLI—it's done via regular `git push`. You can (and in my opinion *should*) have the CLI installed even if you are deploying via GitHub.

In this instance, you could use [`heroku run`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-run) to create your Django superuser via a [one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos):

```
heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser
```

This is the most straightforward solution.

Here are some other reasons you might want to have the CLI installed:

- To manage addons
- To scale your app
- To upgrade your app's [stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack)
- To configure [multiple buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app), e.g. to use Node.js and Python in the same app
- To view your app's logs
- To enable HTTPS on your custom domain using [Automated Certificate Management](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management)
- To use the Docker registry and deployment
- ...

If you want to go down this path, [install the CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) and then [log in by running `heroku login`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#getting-started).

> If there isn't a way without using the Heroku CLI, could someone tell me how I would init the Heroku git repository, considering the fact that I already have a GitHub repository that I have been using

After installing the CLI, `cd` into your project directory and tell Heroku which app that code belongs to by running [`heroku git:remote -a <your-app-name>`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-git-remote).

This adds a Heroku remote but will not change any existing remotes. For example, if you were previously using `git push origin` to push to GitHub you'll still be able to do that.

After doing that you should be able to use `heroku run` as I showed above.